# java: is the function thread-safe in hashmap.put(key, function())?

Tags: java

I want to put a value returned from a function into ConcurrentHashmap like that

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

public void process() {
    map.put(key, function());
}

public Object function() {
    return anyObject;
}
```

May I know the function (e.g. function()) is thread-safe or not?
Please advise if there is any tutorial 
Thanks.

Comment: He wants the return value of function to be stored in the map... look at process()...

Comment: the function (e.g. function()) is just an example to return object which is then save to the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call itself in not thread-safe, only put operation atomic.

Instead you can use guava

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .concurrencyLevel(4)
   .weakKeys()
   .maximumSize(10000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph apply(Key key) {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Please notice **makeComputingMap()** call

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

Comment: what is the meaning of "call itself" ?

Comment: i mean you need to place call to the function() inside makeComputingMap()

Comment: thanks but i just want to stick on J2SE 1.5+ only, can you advise?

Comment: Computing maps have been deprecated in favor of `LoadingCache` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Read / Write Locks in Java.

Example:

```
class X {
  ReadWriteLock rw;

  public void read() throws InterruptedException { 
    rw.readLock().acquire();
    try {
      // ... do the read
    } finally {
      rw.readlock().release()
    }
 }

 public void write() throws InterruptedException { 
     rw.writeLock().acquire();
     try {
       // ... do the write
     } finally {
       rw.writelock().release()
     }
   }
 }
```

Ref:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/232685/threads/java/Concurrent-access-HashMap
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html